# How to load actual dependencies into a Angularjs test with Jasmine and Karma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have been looking around online, but seems, no one really injecting the actual dependencies into a unit test for Angularjs using Jasmine and Karma.

I think there is definitely a separation of concern for the testing process, but I also would like to know how it integrated well with current dependencies in use... so just in case a dependencies is not working well with my component, I will be aware of it!

So, I wonder how can I inject the actual dependencies? So far I found online articles are all about mocking it with a fake one... But I want to use the actual one. Right now, when I enter `karma start` I am getting a error of `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: _Provider <- _ <-MyService`

I inject services in forEach block like this

`beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_MyService_) {`

I wonder if its because I am not using the fake service?

```
describe('MyCtrl', function() {

  //Data Exposure Prep
  var $controller;
  var $rootScope;
  var $scope;
  var controller;
  var MyService;

  dd1 = {
    itinerary: globalMockData.d1,//I stored globalMockData somewhere else
  };

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myapp'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('MyCtrl', { $scope: $scope }, dd1);
  }));

  //BASIC INFO
  describe('should receive sth', function() {
    it('finds sth', function() {
      expect(controller.answer).toBeDefined();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: What will help us is a descripton of your code or a plunker.. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Dsafds posted example

Answer (score -1):

It really depend on your Controlller implementation. 
If you're using scope, you'll probably want to test things on controller's scope, not on the controller itself.

Testing controller with $scope

```
function MyController($scope, MyService) {
 $scope.greetUpperCase = function(name) {
  return MyService.greet(name).toUpperCase();
 }
}
```

Basically, when you’re working with $scope, you don’t really care about the controller itself, since it’s doing everything on it’s scope.

So, we will need to:

inject $rootScope
create a new scope
inject it to a new controller
test the $scope

```
it('test greetUpperCase()', function() {
 var myScope = $rootScope.$new();
 $controller('MyController', {
  $scope: myScope
 });
 expect(myScope .greetUpperCase('bob')).toBe('HELLO BOB');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/pkhaxmdg/

Comment: I have `controllerAs` implementation in this case. thanks for bring that up. :)

Comment: however, its deal with the service that's has been injected into the controller... I wonder does that mean, I have to do `this.MyService = MyService` to make the service test mockable? Thought?

Comment: If you want to test your controller, you'de like to mock the servicer. check out my post: https://ronapelbaum.wordpress.com/2016/02/22/angular-controller-test-with-di-use-inject/

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).